# How to filter out black frames from ffmpeg command that takes screenshots?

Tags: ffmpeg

I'm using this command to create screenshots from a video, each time there is a frame change.

`ffmpeg -i "$video_file" -filter_complex "select=bitor(gt(scene\,0.5)\,eq(n\,0))" -vsync drop "$frames_dir/%04d.jpg"`

It seems to work pretty well, but there are a few black images in the screenshots that I'd like to remove.

I'm not well versed in advanced ffmpeg commands and I think the command above can be adapted to throw away the black frames. Does anybody know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [blackframe](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#blackframe) and [metadata](http://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#metadata_002c-ametadata) filters after select.

```
ffmpeg -i "$video_file" -filter:v "select=bitor(gt(scene\,0.5)\,eq(n\,0)),blackframe=amount=1,metadata=mode=select:key=lavfi.blackframe.pblack:value=95:function=less" -vsync drop "$frames_dir/%04d.jpg"
```